# How to apply Fourier Transform to a color image and inverse Fourier Transform to a gray image?

Tags: image, image-processing, filtering, fft, visualization

How to apply Fourier Transform to a color image?

**[Part 1]**

My guess is that we can separate the color image by 3 channels (R, G, B).
And then, do the Fourier Transform for each R, G, B image. 
After that, sum up three frequency domain images. (Let say these three images (1), (2), (3))

We might get a summed frequency domain image, so we are able to apply a high pass filter or low pass filter.

**Is my guess correct? (first question)**

**[Part 2]**

Once applying the filtering, I need to convert the one channel image to a color space image (like original image that has RGB channel)

So here is my another guess to convert one channel image to a color space image

Since we know which pixel was filtered, we can also mask (1), (2), and (3). (making corresponding pixels '0') After this, it is possible to convert (1) to the red channel color image, and (2) to the green, and (3) to blue one. Finally we can sum all these converted images and get the filtered color image.

**Does this work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that does not work.

If you want to apply a convolution to a color image, you should apply the convolution to each channel independently.

[**Justification:** In the spatial domain, a convolution is a weighted average of a local neighborhood for each output pixel. An average (whether weighted or not) of a set of vectors (we see here each pixel as a vector with 3 components in the case of an RGB image) is computed by averaging each vector element (dimension) separately.]

The Fourier-domain filtering is a convolution, so the above applies to your filtering as well: compute the FFT of each channel independently, apply your filtering to each channel independently, then IFFT each channel independently. The resulting channels are the channels of your filtered image.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!